# Get value from dataLayer.push

Tags: javascript, jquery, google-datalayer

after finishing order on my eshop, there is this part of code:

```
dataLayer.push({
'event': 'trackTrans', 
'ecommerce': {
    'purchase': {
      'actionField': {
        'id': 'XXX',                         
        'affiliation': 'My eshop',
        'revenue': '158.99',                     
        'shipping': '00',
        'coupon': ''
      },
      'products': [

{'name': 'Microsoft Office',
 'id': 'XXX',
 'category': 'Microsoft', 
 'price': 158.99, 
 'quantity': 1}

]
    }
  }
});
```

I'm trying to save value of `revenue` into variable but I fail to reach revenue's value, how do I do it?

Thanks a lot.

Comment: I tried var valueOfOrder = dataLayer.ecommerce.purchase.actionField.revenue; but that doesnt work

Comment: As you use push `dataLayer` is most likely an array. So using `dataLayer[0]` might work. Also your value is a string, so you'll likely need to convert it to a number.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

dataLayer is an array of objects so you should rather use something like: `dataLayer[x].ecommerce.purchase.actionField.revenue` where **x** is position of your object (you can use `[dataLayer.length -1]` for latest object)